# Two soundcards on RPi3?

Tags: hifiberry

The RPI 3 seems to be fast enough for digital low-highpass filtering of sound.
Can I connect two hifiberry dac+ cards and send divide left and right channels through high and lowpass filters direct to my poweramps?

Comment: Are you sure you can stack two hifiberry boards together? I don't have that impression.

Comment: @Dmitrygrigoryev There's some brief discussion [here](https://support.hifiberry.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201494002-Multi-channel-surround-Amp-) that puts a 2-channel limit on I2S. I think that rules out stacking?

Comment: @fonsb, have you considered using a pair of USB sound cards?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're trying to build a [crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_crossover)?

You can't, to the best of my knowledge, stack multiple HiFiBerry DACs for more outputs. Their [help pages](https://support.hifiberry.com/hc/en-us/articles/205376201-GPIO-usage-of-HiFiBerry-boards) have an outline of which pins are used for what.

Personally, I'd go for an outboard crossover unit of some kind. It'll cost more, but stand a higher chance of success when you're already fighting against the Pi's limited capabilities and godawful audio output.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for filters on http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Music-Server-With-Built-in-Crossover-/?ALLSTEPS, but mr.J.Ruby uses the hdmi output and uses the receiver to decode to analog.
But I am sure the rpi3 is more than fast and can be used for filtering.
I like the hifiberry dac+ pro card it sounds perfect. Look at this article: www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Music-Server-With-Built-in-Crossover-/?ALLSTEPS